# Show intervals in Progress bar of Audio- HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html5-audio

I would like to show 10 seconds Mark / 30 Seconds mark on 5 min audio file. 
The mark can be a small dark line. How can I do it.

Will this work properly?

```
//getting the audio ID
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
// setting the duration to 10 seconds
audio.duration = 10;
//setting the duration to a class name
audio.duration.classList.add("otherclass");
```

Comment: No. The duration property simply returns the length of the audio (in seconds). You can't set it. And you can't give it a class name. Please clarify what you are tying to do.

Comment: I have a default progress bar. at certain points I need to give a mark. The mark denotes it is 10 seconds. i.e., for every 10 seconds I need to give a mark on the progress bar. Should I design the progress bar or I should create new by myself.

Comment: If you need a set custom controls, you should design them yourself. You can't modify the default player UI.